# Use HashLocation Strategy without having a # in the URL Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Due to getting 404 issue in gh-pages i moved to HashLocation Strategy .
Now i donot get the 404 error but my url contains a #

like `rajat0890.github.io/Singh/#home`.

How can i make use of the Hashlocation Strategy without having the # in the URL.

like in Angular JS `$locationProvider.html5mode(true);`

Please help its important

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Not even a work around

Comment: You should implement [HTML5 URLs](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles, recommended by Angular team.

Comment: Can you please give a small example